# LINQ query succeeding/error depends on one arbitrary assignment statement

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, join, left-join

Here is my LINQ query in C#:

```
var q =
    from a in context.tableA.Where(s => s.field1 == id)    //I'm querying by "id"
    from b in context.tableB.Where(s => s.field1 == a.field1)
    from c in context.tableC.Where(s => s.field2 == b.field2).DefaultIfEmpty() //left join
    from d in context.tableD.Where(s => s.field3 == b.field3).DefaultIfEmpty()
    from e in context.tableE.Where(s => s.field4 == b.field4).DefaultIfEmpty()

    select new CustomObject()
    {
        CustomObject_fieldA = a.someField,
        CustomObject_fieldB = b.someField,

            //some other fields assigned...

        CustomObject_fieldC = c.someField,
        CustomObject_fieldD = d.someField,
        CustomObject_fieldE = e.someField     // <-- THIS LINE
    }
```

So for clarification, my tables are structured like this:

```
tableA:    int field1
tableB:    int field1   int field2   int field3   int field4
tableC:                 int field2
tableD:                              int field3
tableE:                                           int field4
```

*MY PROBLEM*

If I comment out `THIS LINE` then the query will succeed.

If I leave `THIS LINE` uncommented, then the query will hang, and give `EntityCommandExecutionException` error (a `Timeout expired` error).

Since I'm doing left joins, I know that `e` could be `NULL`. But I've done some tests that tell me this is not causing the error.

*--TEST 1--*

First, comment out `THIS LINE`. Then, `c` and `d` may or may not be `NULL`, and the query will succeed regardless of whether `c` or `d` are `NULL`.

*--Test 2--*

Uncomment `THIS LINE`. Whether `e` is `NULL` or not, the query will always fail (hang with the error given above).

*QUESTION*

I have run lots of testing and narrowed the success/failure(hanging) to depending on the commenting or uncommenting of `THIS LINE`.

**Does anyone know why this is happening and how to fix it?**

*EDIT for clarification*

```
// in the CustomObject.cs file, some of the properties are
public string CustomObject_fieldA { get; set; }
public string CustomObject_fieldB { get; set; }
public string CustomObject_fieldC { get; set; }
public string CustomObject_fieldD { get; set; }
public string CustomObject_fieldE { get; set; }
```

Comment: Yes it is a property with a setter, see my edit at the bottom. And no, the only purpose of it is to store that value.

Comment: What are the data types for *field2*,  *field3*, and *field4*?

Comment: they are all `int`. updated question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're getting a Timeout error on execution of the LINQ query, my recommendation would be to generate the SQL for your LINQ query and then run that through a profiler to see what the query optimizer is doing.

```
var sql = ((System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery)q).ToTraceString();
```

If you're working with a large dataset a timeout could occur from an unoptimized join or perhaps just a DB server that is running low on resources. Either way the profiler should tell you what's really happening with the timeout.

Comment: I realize that this doesn't necessarily answer the question directly, but i don't have enough rep to add the above as a comment. If the OP does what i suggest he/she will likely discover the problem with the LINQ query.